# with quotation mark and without quotation mark, what is the difference

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

For the following code, I wish to find the minimun cp item which has the lowest xerror

```
data(iris)
install.packages("rpart")
library(rpart)
set.seed(161)
tree.model1<-rpart(Sepal.Length~., data = iris)
install.packages("rpart.plot")
library(rpart.plot)
rpart.plot(tree.model1)
tree.model2<-rpart(Sepal.Length~., data = iris, cp=0.005)
tree.model2$cptable
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
rpart.plot(tree.model1)
rpart.plot(tree.model2)
which.min(tree.model2$cptable[,"xerror"])
```

my question is focused on the last line, what if I put
`which.min(tree.model2$cptable[, xerror]` it doesn't work

what is the function of put the quotation mark here?

Comment: With the quotation mark, you are looking at the column whose name is `"xerror"`.  Without the quotation marks, you're looking at the column whose name is given by *the value of the variable whose name is `xerror`*.  Since `xerror` doesn't exist, you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R syntax dictates the use of quotation marks when indexing with strings. I assume your confusion is that since `xerror` is a variable name and you normally use it without quoting in other lines, you expect it to be the same. However, you must see the difference between the index of a variable and the variable itself.

Therefore the use of `[]` (indexing) does not allow for you to use `xerror` without quotation but it will work when you use `which.min(tree.model2$cptable[,4])` for instance, since `xerror` is the 4th column (another index for `"xerror"`) in the `cptable`.

You'll start to pick these up as you progress further using R. Another tip would be to neatly write and comment your code so both you and others can understand easily.